# What is the DB2 application db2evmg_DB2DETAILDEA

Tags: db2, windows-server-2003

What is the DB2 application **db2evmg_DB2DETAILDEA** and how do I change its authorizatrion ID.
I can see it running in the activity monitor.

Regards and thanks,

Joe

Comment: Have found the following but still don't know how to change the authorization ID  [IBM DB2 PROCESS MODEL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0008930.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process is a system-generated process that supports the event monitor DB2DETAILDEADLOCK.  This event monitor gets created when the database is created, and is set to automatically start when the database is activated.

The db2evmg runs using the authorization ID of the ID that created the event monitor.  You can see this by looking at the `DEFINER` column of `SYSCAT.EVENTMONITORS`.  Usually, this ID corresponds to the instance owner ID (i.e., the ID that the "DB2 - DB2" service runs under), because this particular event monitor is created when you issue the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

However, if you have changed the ID that the DB2 service runs as, or if you have restored the database to a different DB2 instance (using a different ID), the owner (and the auth ID of the db2evmg process) will still show what it was when the database was created.

It does not hurt anything if the auth ID for the event monitor is out of whack.  However, if you want to change this, then you would have to first stop the event monitor, and then drop and recreate it.